# Google map marker size change upon zoom Level change

Tags: android

Anyways I can allow for Google maps v2 markers to zoom in /zoom out when I I zoom the map? Basically like a circle, the size would change with the zoom level

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something when zooming, you can create a custom Mapview which extends the original MapView, and just override dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas).

With adding a little listener, you can do whatever you want in the callback. Something like this;

```
@Override
 protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas canvas){
 super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
 if (getZoomLevel() != lastZoomLevel) { 
if (listener != null) { 
listener.onZoom(lastZoomLevel, getZoomLevel());
 } 
lastZoomLevel = getZoomLevel(); 
} }
```

Comment: Good idea.. Thank you :) although I am using mapfragment