# How to remove google map default geofence or radius?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2, geofencing

I have used custom circle to draw Geo fencing, but some time Google it self shows its default light blue Geo fence circle. 
 It create problem, like its displaying 2 radius in my map.

So how can I remove default Geo fencing in my application.

Answer (score 2):

use `map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);` and create your own marker to display current location

```
googleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener locationListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            drawMarker(location);

            private void drawMarker(Location location) {

                LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude());
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(currentPosition)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                        .title("my position"));

            }

        };

        map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(locationListener);
```

Comment: thanks for reply its work for me but there is one issue blue dots which show current location that cant show i have put custom circle over there but when i zoom in map its radius is increase.

Comment: the circle covers the constant area, so whenever you zoom in the more area it should cover. why do you want circle

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654110/google-map-marker-size-change-upon-zoom-level-change?rq=1

Comment: i cant get where i have to put dispatch draw method cant find in override method list.

Comment: use should always use BitmapDescriptor for maiker icons. try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32187898/6880632

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163640/discussion-between-kapil-parmar-and-shailendrasinh-gohil).